C++ auto template parameter deduction not working in GCC 14 unlike its older versions and Clang
The following snippet is accepted by GCC 13 and older, as well as all versions of Clang, but not by GCC 14. Either of the two suggested edits make GCC 14 accept the code as well.
#include <iostream>

template <int T> struct A { int value = T; };

// Replacing 'unsigned char' with 'int' makes it work with GCC 14:
template <unsigned char X> using B = A<X>;

// Or, replacing 'auto' with 'int' makes it work with GCC 14:
template <auto X>
void foo(B<X>& mat) noexcept
{
    std::cout << mat.value << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    A<2> mat;
    foo(mat);
}

The error emitted by GCC 14 is as follows, saying that the auto template parameter cannot be deduced unless auto is replaced with a specific type or the non-type template parameter of the alias has the same type as that of the aliased template:
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:18:8: error: no matching function for call to 'foo(A<2>&)'
   18 |     foo(mat);
      |     ~~~^~~~~
<source>:10:6: note: candidate: 'template<auto X> void foo(B<((unsigned char)X)>&)'
   10 | void foo(B<X>& mat) noexcept
      |      ^~~
<source>:10:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:18:8: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'X'
   18 |     foo(mat);
      |     ~~~^~~~~

Which compiler is correct?

gcc is correct to reject it. Implicit type conversion should not  be used when decucing template types.

@PepijnKramer Thanks! Can you please cite the Specification?

For example see this answer : Implicit type conversion with templated function parameters (but the same rules apply for all templates)

I'm inclined to think that gcc is incorrect, because template<auto X> should be deduced as template<int X>, at which point there is no problem: https://godbolt.org/z/aGeaK4aG3

It should compile.
Paragraph 13.4.3/2 describes argument deduction:

The value of a non-type template-parameter P of (possibly deduced)
type T is determined from its template argument A as follows. If T is
not a class type and A is not a braced-init-list, A shall be a
converted constant expression (7.7) of type T; the value of P is A (as
converted)

The process of conversion is described in 7.7/13:

A converted constant expression of type T is an expression, implicitly
converted to type T, where the converted expression is a constant
expression and the implicit conversion sequence contains only <skipped...>
integral conversions (7.3.9) other than narrowing conversions (9.4.5),

The description of narrowing conversions we find in 9.4.5/7, which also details which conversions are excluded from this:

A narrowing conversion is an implicit conversion ...
(7.4) — from an integer type or unscoped enumeration type to an integer type that
cannot represent all the values of the original type, except where
(7.4.1) — the source is a bit-field whose width w is less than that of
its type (or, for an enumeration type, its underlying type) and the
target type can represent all the values of a hypothetical extended
integer type with width w and with the same signedness as the original
type or (7.4.2) — the source is a constant expression whose value
after integral promotions will fit into the target type

The last bullet describes the current case, integer value 2 fits the target type unsigned char, so it's excluded from narrowing conversion restrictions.
